# How to write a parameterized query for multiple row insert in a table?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, bulkinsert

I have a `SQLCommand` object with `CommandText` as below:

```
 insert into [table] (field1, field2, field3) 
    select (value11, value12, value13), 
    select(value21, value22, value23),
    select(value20001,value20002)(value20003)
```

I have all these values stored in a list of such objects. You can consider them to be 6000 variables(not constant, but user supplied) that i have with me

How can I prevent SQL injection in this and make this query parameterized?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check sql injection using c# code.

For SQL SERVER 2008 or above

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'test'), (2, 'test 2'), (3, 'test 2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(yourconnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText= "insert into [table] (field1, field2, field3) 
select (@Parameter1, @parameter2, @parameter3)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", "your value of 1st parameter");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", "your value of 2nd parameter");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter3", "your value of 3rd parameter");
con.Open();
int TotalRowsAffected= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

if you have multiple insert then can do something like this

```
for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", dt.Rows[0][i]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", dt.Rows[0][i]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter3", dt.Rows[0][i]);

}
```

Comment: But the parameters here will be overridden.... I want all the 2000*3 parameters to be a part of 1 CommandText.

Comment: @user2694330 Why? That makes no sense. Your list of objects is basically a set of rows once it comes to the Db. They'd have the same set of parameters used over and over.